# Select method in List<t> Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, dataset

I have an asp.net application, and now I am using datasets for data manipulation. I recently started to convert this dataset to a List collection. But, in some places it doesn't work. One is that in my old version I am using `datarow[] drow =  dataset.datatable.select(searchcriteria)`. But in the List collection there is no method available for finding particular values. Is there any way for me to select some values according with my search criteria? I want to know if this is possible. Please help me.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Well, to start with `List<T>` *does* have the [`FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) and [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) methods - but the more idiomatic, modern approach is to use LINQ:

```
// Find all the people older than 30
var query1 = list.Where(person => person.Age > 30);

// Find each person's name
var query2 = list.Select(person => person.Name);
```

You'll need a using directive in your file to make this work:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Note that these don't use strings to express predicates and projects - they use delegates, usually created from lambda expressions as above.

If lambda expressions and LINQ are new to you, I would suggest you get a book covering LINQ first, such as [LINQ in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988169), [Pro LINQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597893), [C# 4 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596800959) or my own [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/affiliate/idevaffiliate.php?id=876_230). You certainly *can* learn LINQ just from web tutorials, but I think it's such an important technology, it's worth taking the time to learn it thoroughly.

Answer (score 9):

you can also try

```
var query = from p in list
            where p.Age > 18
            select p;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
var result = from i in list
             where i.age > 45
             select i;
```

Using lambda expression please use this Statement:

```
var result = list.where(i => i.age > 45);
```

Answer (score 4):

Generic [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) have the [`Where<T>(Func<T, Boolean>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method that can be used to filter data.

In your case with a row array:

```
var rows = rowsArray.Where(row => row["LastName"].ToString().StartsWith("a"));
```

If you are using [`DataRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to cast it first.

```
var rows = dataTableRows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row["LastName"].ToString().StartsWith("a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a script but to make a join, maybe I can help you

```
string Email = String.Join(", ", Emails.Where(i => i.Email != "").Select(i => i.Email).Distinct());
```