# C#: Duplicating of Objects when adding item to List

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am working on a SharePoint webpart which requires retrieval of data using LINQ. I needed the result to be on a List-type object so that I can use the result within, freely.

But the issue is that, for the declared C# List-type with an custom object casted on it; For every new item added into the list, the object that were added earlier were changed to the latest value of the object that just entered the list.

Here is a sample code of what I wrote:

```
List<ItemEntity> LocalItemList = new List<ItemEntity>();

var linqQuery = from item in LinqList;
                where item.Expire > DateTime.Now
                select new
                {
                    item.Title,
                    item.Message
                }

foreach (var retrievedItem in linqQuery){
    //this is an entity class object, "tempItemEntity".
    ItemEntity tempItemEntity = new ItemEntity();

    tempItemEntity.Author = retrievedItem.Title;
    tempItemEntity.Message = retrievedItem.Message;

    LocalItemList.Add(tempItemEntity);
}

/* From here on is my test printing loop to see the returned result. The results are shown below. */
```

Here is the result printed from the List, "LocalItemList":

**Expected Result**

These are the result that I am expecting.

```
LocalItemList[0] = "Title1" + "Message1"
LocalItemList[1] = "Title2" + "Message2"
LocalItemList[2] = "Title3" + "Message3"
```

**Returned Result**

Instead, these were the results returned.

```
LocalItemList[0] = "Title3" + "Message3"
LocalItemList[1] = "Title3" + "Message3"
LocalItemList[2] = "Title3" + "Message3"
```

It seemed to me that for every new item added to the list, the previous index gets updated and changed into the latest added item. Why is this so?

If you are talking about the object referencing is not correct, do correct me.

p.s. Apparently, if the List is not casted in the following manner, `List<Object>`, and instead this way, `List<String>`, the results are correct.

---

**Update**

I was searching around the forum and found the following questions who had similar issue with me:

1. [Duplicate List<T>.Add(T item) Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510822/duplicate-listt-addt-item-items)
2. [Select method in List<t> Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801748/select-method-in-listt-collection)

But I have problem implementing the probable solution from the answer given in Link #1.

---

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does your `linqQuery` variable contain the correct values?

Comment: @keyboardP Yes, it contains the correct values in `linqQuery`. I have tested it and the `linqQuery` returns the correct result; but i will like to have the information to be inserted into a (C#) list..

Comment: The bug might be in your test printing loop.

Comment: @shamp00: not really. it works fine actually when the `<cast type>` is of other types like `List<String>...` or `List<Int>...` which are okay! But not `List<Object>...`

Comment: Have you tried a ToList() in linqQuery?